# A question on double dual of C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A, B$ be the C*-algebra. Assume $A$ is nonunital, $B$ is unital and $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ is a contractive completely positive map.

Then we consider the double adjoint map $\phi^{**}: A^{**}\rightarrow B^{**}$. Identifying double duals with enveloping von Neumann algebras, **can we checks that $\phi^{**}$ maps positive operators to positive operators?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key observation is that the identification between $A^{**}$ and the enveloping von Neumann algebra preserves positivity. So, if $\alpha\in A^{**}_+$, we can find a net $\{a_n\}\in A_+$ with $a_n\to\alpha$ in the $w^*$-topology (every $a\in A''_+$ is a weak-limit of elements in $A_+$).

Now let $f\in B^*_+$. Then
$$
(\phi^{**}\alpha)f=\alpha(\phi^*f)=\lim_na_n(\phi^*f)=\lim_n f(\phi(a_n))\geq0,
$$
using that $\phi$, $f$ are positive.

Comment: I still have a simple question why does $(\phi^{**}\alpha)f=\alpha(\phi^*f)$ hold?

Comment: By definition of $\phi^{**}$. More precisely, by definition of the adjoint map.